# How to GET data from mongoDB ATLAS and display in React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am new to MERN stack and been working on a project that uses different driver information entered from the user and display that information back to the user in a table. I have successfully connected to MongoDB Atlas and also can enter data using my front end but I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve the data back to the front end. Can y'all help me fetch the data back and how I can present it in a tabular format.
Thanks in advance.

```
//driver model
onst mongoose = require('mongoose');
const DriverSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{type: String, required:true},
    email:{type: String, required:true},
    phone:{type: Number, required:true},
    address:{type:String, required:true},
    country:{type: String, required:true}
});

const DriverModel = mongoose.model("drivers", DriverSchema)
module.exports = DriverModel;
```

```
//routes
const router= require('express').Router();
let Driver = require('../models/driver');

router.route('/getDrivers').get((req, res) =>{
    Driver.find()
    .then(drivers => res.json(drivers))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: '+ err));

}
)

router.route('/createDrivers').post((req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const phone = req.body.phone;
    const address = req.body.address;
    const country =req.body.country;
    const newDriver = new Driver({name, email, phone, address, country});
  
    newDriver.save()
      .then(() => res.json('Driver added!'))
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
  });
  
  router.route('/:id').get((req,res)=> {
      Driver.findById(req.params.id)
      .then(drivers => res.json(drivers))
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
  })

  router.route('/:id').delete((req, res) => {
    Driver.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
      .then(() => res.json('Driver deleted.'))
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
  });

  router.route('/update/:id').post((req, res) => {
    Driver.findById(req.params.id)
      .then(driver => {
        driver.name = req.body.name;
        driver.email = req.body.email;
        driver.phone = req.body.phone;
        driver.address = req.body.address;
        driver.country =req.body.country;
  
        driver.save()
          .then(() => res.json('Driver updated!'))
          .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
  });

  module.exports = router;
```

```
//frontend
import React from 'react';
import Sidebar from '../../components/sidebar/Sidebar';
import Navbar from '../../components/navbar/Navbar';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import "./dbtrial.scss" ;
import Axios from "axios";
function Dbtrial() {
    
    const [listOfDrivers, setListOfDrivers]= useState([]);
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState(0);
    const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
    const [country, setCountry] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchDrivers= async () =>{
        try{
          const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/driver/getDrivers")
          if(!response.ok) throw Error('Did not recieve expected data');
          const listDrivers = await response.json();
          console.log(listDrivers);
          setListOfDrivers(listDrivers);
          setFetchError(null);
        } catch(err){
          setFetchError(err.message)
        }
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        (async () => await fetchDrivers())();
      }, 2000)
      //(async () => await fetchDrivers())();
    }, [])
        
    const createDrivers = () =>{
      Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/createDrivers", {
        name, 
        email, 
        phone, 
        address,
        country,
      }).then((response) =>{
        setListOfDrivers([...listOfDrivers,
        {
          name, email, phone, address,
          country,
        },
      ]);
        //alert("Driver added!");
      });
    } 
    
    return (
        <div className="db">
            <Sidebar />
            <div className="dbq">
                <Navbar />
                <div className="formInput">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="name"  onChange={(event) => {
                      setName(event.target.value);
                      }} />
                </div>
                <div className="formInput">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="email"  onChange={(event)=> {setEmail(event.target.value);}}/>
                </div>
                <div className="formInput">
                    <label>Phonenumber</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="0923668881 "  onChange={(event) => {setPhone(event.target.value);}}/>
                    </div>
                <div className="formInput">
                    <label>Address</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Addis Ababa" onChange={(event)=> {setAddress(event.target.value);}}/>
                </div>
                <div className="formInput">
                    <label>Country</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="country" onChange={(event) => {setCountry(event.target.value);}}/>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={createDrivers}>Send</button>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Dbtrial
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your backend, your router functions don't seem to use

```
res.send
```

Where you are doing res.json, you can do something like

```
res.status(200).send(responseData)
```

So in `router.routes.findById`' then callback, instead of:

```
.then(drivers => 
   res.json(drivers))
```

You can have

```
.then(drivers => 
   res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(drivers)) //maybe you don't need to use JSON.stringify here
```

In your frontend, I'm not sure what `response.data` will be defined after your api call. To be sure what properties the response has, you can `console.dir(response.data)`, `console.dir(response.json())` and check the result in the browser console. (Not too familiar with axios) If the result is your driver array, you can do like are already doing with `setDriverList` to set the state, but probably with the result of, or a part of the result of `response.data` or `response.data.devices` or something like that.

So I would do something like

```
//...api call
.then((response) => {
    if(response.status === 200){
        setDriverList(response.data.drivers) //or response.data or whatever
    }
})
```

Comment: should I append that to the router.route.findByID?

Comment: Exactly, where you have `then(... res.json`, you should have `res.send`, or `res.status.send`.

Comment: Okay, is there anything I need to add to the frontend to fetch the data so that it appears on the app

Comment: It looks like nearly there - just not sure if `response.data` will get you what you want. I would replace the call to set the state with a `console.log(response.json())` just to see what is in there but I assume you can set state with the result

Comment: will the ```console.log(response.json())``` return the values in the browser console or within the app itself? How can I set the state with the result ?

Comment: I suggest using `console.log` just to print the result in the browser console, so you can be sure you have the result you want while developing. The way you are setting `setDriverList` looks correct, I just think the value of `result.data` is probably undefined.

Comment: Apologies, just realised I am wrong above - `result.data` is valid, I was thinking of a different library. Have updated the answer.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your continued support. I have been able to retrieve the data to the browser console using a different api call which I have edited above  in the `useEffect()`

Comment: That looks good. If the value of `listDrivers` looks like an array when you log it out, then the call to `setDriverList` should be setting the state ok now, right?

Comment: Yes I have successfully fetched the data to the application. Thank you for your time. Have a nice day.